# push docker image to nexus get an error code 405

Tags: windows, docker, nexus

I am trying to push my docker image to my private registry.
I use Nexus 3 as docker registry.

Docker version: V23.0.5 on windows 11.

Nexus version: Sonatype Nexus repository manager OSS 3.29.1-01

When I am trying to push my image to my Nexus server, I got an error code 405.

```bash
PS D:\> docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
192.168.25.57:8081/apc   mytag     d2a92743e4cf   30 minutes ago   1.54GB
apc                      latest    d2a92743e4cf   30 minutes ago   1.54GB
PS D:\> docker tag d2a92743e4cf  idocker.io:8081/apc:mytag
PS D:\> docker push idocker.io:8081/apc:mytag
The push refers to repository [idocker.io:8081/apc]
bf84219fbbbc: Preparing
error parsing HTTP 405 response body: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n"
```

Here is my deamon.json file:

```json
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.25.57:8081",
    "idocker.io:8081"
  ]
}
```

When I am trying to login using docker login -p password -u username, I got an error of Client.Timeout error

I tryed search the whole net, but find nothing to solve my problem.
I read the docker daemon file full-example, nothing help.

It seems that I make a basic mistake that nobody would have, but hard to workout.

Comment: Is your Nexus registry really hosted at **idocker.io** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP `192.168.25.57` in your configuration file is a local machine IP. I'm assuming you're running the registry in the same computer you're trying to push from. If you want to use a domain for which you do not have the DNS as your hostname, I would suggest editing your hosts file and overriding `idocker.io` to that same local IP.

You can find the hosts file in your Windows installation drive, at `Windows > System32 > drivers > etc > hosts`. Open the file with any text editor, with administrative privileges, and add the following line at the end of it:

```
192.168.25.57 idocker.io
```

Save and close it. After doing so, your machine will resolve `idocker.io` to the specified IP, and thus you will be able to use it as your local Docker registry. However, it should go without saying that **said registry will not be publicly available**.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for your answering. I found out that the problem caused by port, this server is behind a firewall, and that server closed the privilege of access port 8083 which I used for push my image.